# Python fmask from command line or in Python script

Tags: qgis, python, saga, command-line, cloud-cover

I'd like to mask some clouds in Sentinel-2-Images with the `python-fmask`-library. As I'm not too experienced with Python and remote sensing, I have some questions. 
When I installed the library I automatically could execute the command-line-tools. The `fmask_sentinel2stacked.py` works from the command line when giving as input the `.safe`-directory, as described here: http://www.pythonfmask.org/en/latest/
But the library also does have some "python-specific" modules like `fmask.py` and `config.py`. In `fmask.py` the function `doFmask()` takes as input two instances of other classes. These instances contain information about, for example the thermal bands. As Sentinel-2 does not have thermal bands there is already the first confusion. 
Actually I just wanted to ask if someone already has experience in using this package and what are the differences in using the command line interface vs. the import of Python modules.

Comment: Did you solve your question ( the one not in the title, I mean, it should have been named differently or split your two question I think).
As far as I read on documentation, it is true that fmask counts over thermal bands, then given that s2 lacks of them, I suppose that they adapted the code to this fact, so I would expect it to be a bit less performant/accurate masking sentinel than landsat. But, who knows. Maybe inside they have found a tweak to explore extra red bands and higher resolution of sentinel 2 to overcome the thermal band difficulty. Hope this 2-cents help anyone interested in th

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `.SAFE` directory has the same structure as the official one. 
Note: it will be easier to run py-mask in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Install fmask to conda environment as per documentation (using conda env).

```
import os

from fmask.cmdline import sentinel2Stacked


safe_dir = 'S2A_MSIL1C_20200831T155911_N0209_R097_T17SPU_20200831T200101.SAFE'

out_img_file = 'cloud4.img'

sentinel2Stacked.mainRoutine(['--safedir', safe_dir, '-o', out_img_file])

print('Completed running Fmask on SAFE file')
```

This should output 'cloud4.img'